# End of script output before headers Python

Tags: python, xampp

---

I created Hello world script in python. Everytime I try to run it web browser sends me Error 500

> Error message: 
>   End of script output before headers: test.py

Script:

```
#!C:\Python35\python.exe

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>")
print("<H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>")
print("Hello, world!")
```

This is apache error output

```
End of script output before headers: test.py
AH01215: C:\\Python35\\python.exe: can't open file '%L': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/test.py
```

Comment: is there a file "test.py" in C:/xampp/cgi-bin/?

Comment: Yes, file "test.py" is in cgi-bin folder

Comment: Please show us the command how you execute the script

Comment: http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py - This is my command how I execute this script

Comment: Just wondering has anyone resolved this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error when I noticed a python script that worked would open a window and display "Content-type: text/html\n\n" where as the script that would fail opened a window but didn't display "Content-type: text/html\n\n".

I added "print('Content-type: text/html\n\n') as the first line in main() and that fixed it.

Note I was using Geany to test the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of causes of this error. A good first place to look is the Apache CGI log file. The location of this file might be specified in the configuration file (look for the directive 'ScriptLog'). If that's not set up, you might want to do that. Please note that this is distinct from the Apache error log file. The CGI log file might give you a more helpful error message.

Otherwise there can be a problem with the first two rows of the output, which should look something like 'Content-type: text/html' followed by a blank line.

Another possible cause is if the Python script file was edited on a Windows PC before being copied to a Linux server, and the end-of-line endings are still set to the Windows convention. The Windows EOL convention (CR LF) will not work on Linux (LF), and will produce the 'End of script output before headers' error. The EOL problem can be fixed by using, for example, Notepad++ on the Windows side, and clicking the menu item 'Edit', 'EOL Conversion', 'Unix (LF)', then save the file, and re-upload it to Linux.